# Table Variable and Database Scope

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temporary-tables

I am a junior DBA, and I am still confused by database scope.

Now I am learning about local/global temp table and table variables. I saw an example as following:

```
declare @T1 as table 
(   
    col1 int not null
);

insert into @T1(col1) values (10);

exe('select col1 from @T1;');

go
```

When I run it in SQL Server, I got below message:

> (1 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the table variable "@T1".

The message means the insert statement was successful while the exec failed. I am confused because:

1. I don't know why SQL Server considers the `@T1` declaration and the insert statement as one block. My colleague told me to regard them as a stored procedure. But I thought a stored procedure should at least follow `DECLARE...BEGIN...END` format.
2. There is another example right after this one in book:

   ```
   declare @T1 as table 
   (   
        col1 int not null
   );

   insert into @T1(col1) values (10);
   go

   exec('select col1 from @T1;');
   go
   ```

And it gave me same error. I don't know what the book is going to show me by using these 2 examples. Or in another word, I don't understand the use of "GO".

Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

Table variables have the scope of the batch or stored procedure they are run in. There is no need to drop the table variable at the end of a batch, however you will not be able to reference the table variable in consecutive batches.

If you execute the SQL as one block, without the exec, then your `SELECT` will be able to 'see' the table variable and select the data from it.

```
declare @T1 as table 
(   
    col1 int not null
);

insert into @T1(col1) values (10);

select col1 from @T1; -- returns 10

go
```

The `exec` encapsulates a T-SQL batch, so in your example it is in a completely separate batch from the table declaration and the insert statement and therefore the table variable is not in scope.

Exec does not terminate a batch though, the table variable will still be in scope after the exec is run.

```
declare @T1 as table 
(   
    col1 int not null
);

insert into @T1(col1) values (10);

exec('select col1 from @T1;'); -- errors

select col1 from @T1; -- returns 10

go
```

However, the [`GO` command signals the end of a batch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188037.aspx), so placing a `GO` between the `insert` and `select` will also mean you are executing 2 separate batches. You would then also get the error

```
declare @T1 as table 
(   
    col1 int not null
);

insert into @T1(col1) values (10);

exec('select col1 from @T1;'); -- errors

GO

select col1 from @T1; -- errors

GO
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. This example comes from the training kit of "Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012". The examples are trying to show me the visibilities of table variables in different levels.

Comment: @Joann.B Ah ok, so maybe they were showing you examples of what should not work?

Comment: So can I say that the difference between those 2 examples is implicitly or explicitly showing a batch end?

Comment: To your above question: yes it is :)

Comment: And one more question: can you give me some other examples that predicting a start of another batch, just like "exec"?

Comment: So GO is an explicit batch end. The exec is not a batch end, it's executed completely independently of the current batch and the current batch remains in scope after you execute the exec.

Comment: Added some updates to my answer

Comment: That is a wonderful explanation! Thanks very much!

Comment: Really want to vote up your answer but I am lack of reputation :) Anyway, thank you again!